# manipulating DOM elements inside or outside the eventListener

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to add an `click`event when I click on the button, and the page will show what I have typed into the input field:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
document.querySelector(".myButton").addEventListener("click",function()
{
var container = document.querySelector(".contanier");
   container.innerHTML = input;
});
```

this is just work fine, but i want make this code looks strunctre a bit, so i rewite as :

```
var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
var button = document.querySelector(".myButton"); 
var container = document.querySelector(".contanier");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){container.innerHTML = input;});
```

but when I click the button the page just refresh to be blanked, do i have to make DOM inside the `event`so this can work? Could anyone tell me what's the difference after I rewrite this?

sorry i fogort the html code:

```
<body>
<div class="main-container">
   <input type="text" class="js-userInput">
   <button class="myButton">Go!</button>
</div>


 <div class="container"></div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? Is `.myButton` within a `<form>` element?

Comment: In both code blocks your `input` variable is set *once* to the value that the input had when the page first loaded, not the current value when the click event occurs - that line should be inside the event handler. The first code block can't work as shown because it is missing a closing `)`.

Comment: Need HTML, I have a feeling that your button's attributes are a little off.

Comment: Start by doing `button.addEventListener("click",function(){
console.log(input);
container.innerHTML = input;});` to check what the value of input is.

Comment: @guest271314 sorry i forgot the HTML, just added it up there is just a <input>tag with simple input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a type on a `<button>` tag, it [defaults to `type="submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), which causes the form the button belongs to to be submitted to the server.

This causes the same page to reload if a [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) pointing to another URL was not set. If you add `type="button"` it will function as a button without submitting the page. As [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) noted in the comments, you also only get the value of the input box once, on page load, so even with `type=button` it wouldn't work as intended.

When you grab `.value`, you are grabbing a string containing it's value, not a reference to the `.value` property. Instead store a reference to the element and grab the `.value` every time your event handler runs.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input"), // store a reference to the element,
                                             // instead of querying the .value
  button = document.querySelector(".myButton"),
  container = document.querySelector(".container"); // there was a typo in the
                                                    // class name here too, so 
                                                    // the container variable was null.
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  container.innerHTML = input.value; // query the .value here each time it runs
});
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
   <input type="text" class="js-userInput">
   <!-- you need to specify type button so it doesn't
        default to submit, which will reload the page. -->
   <button type="button" class="myButton">Go!</button>
</div>


<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying this into the form then button should have the attribute `type="button"`.
Their another method in
`function ($event) {
$event.preventDefault();}`.
Example
https://plnkr.co/edit/1F5Z7CZOS4P89nEzU7dP?p=preview

Comment: @mystreie If you don't specify a type on a `<button>` tag, it [defaults to `type="submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), which is probably what is causing the page to refresh. As this answer suggests, use `type="button"` and/or [`.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).